# Magento 1.9 magmi after product images import when that product saved from admin it removes the image

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magmi

I have strange issue with magmi import, the product import works with magmi. After import the products and images are displaying in the admin and front but when i update any product from the admin the images of that product are automatically removed. If i upload image from admin it works fine.

It seems like the images are saved but something is missing with Magmi image import.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before importing csv file, Put all the images in repository : /media/import and put only image name while you import the images.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to [this issue](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/183)

in 
App/Code/Local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php

Comment out $this->_removeDuplicates($result); on line 83

Comment out $this->_removeDuplicates($result); on line 293